# Why are attacks pointed to 'Null island' in tools like Norsecorp?

Tags: network, penetration-test, geolocation

Sometimes attacks are directed to this particular location(0°N 0°E) when looking at  [norsecorp](http://map.norsecorp.com):

[image: map]

Does this serve any purpose other than being a location for unknown destinations? How does an attack end up here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those tools use GeoIP databases that map IP addresses to approximate locations to display location data as here is no physical way to tell where data is actually flowing (and there's no guaranteed those DBs are true nor up to date).

Sometimes those databases don't know about a particular IP and return 0,0, which is what you see here.

Comment: Further adding to this answer ... geoIP's that cant be pinpointed to any specific location have been moved to large bodies of water to prevent this: http://fusion.net/story/287592/internet-mapping-glitch-kansas-farm/

Answer (score 0):

As has been answered above it is most likely because there was no valid data for the geolocation field.  The information provided by the likes of geoip is very approximate and does not have a high confidence level beyond the country of origin.  When you are looking at the sources also consider the geolocation is for the observed IP and may not be where an attack is actually located